# What keeps voltage/current/power from flowing into "branch two" from the "Vout" node in the below drawing?

Tags: voltage, power-flow-analysis, flow-control

[image]

I need Vin to go into one of two branches and then continue to Vout, the boxes represent DC-DC converter, one at 20V and another at 15V.

What keeps voltage from going through Branch 1 into Vout node and then into branch 2.
Obviously in the picture it looks like the boxes don't have a ground connection but in reality the boxes have ground connections as can be seen in the picture below
[image]

So what keeps Vout from entering branch 2?

Should I instead flip the design to look like the below picture where the switch is on the left side of the branches?
[image]

Comment: So, make a drawing where all things that are connected are actually connected. We can't guess what your strange, non-standard drawings are supposed to mean. Without knowing exactly what you're talking about how are we able to say anything about your system.

Answer (score 0):

According to your diagram, Vout will indeed appear at the *output* of Branch 2, but no current (and therefore, power) will flow through Branch 2, since its input is an open-circuit.  So there is no problem with the first arrangement, and it is preferable to the second arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the datasheet for the RPX-1.0 is this one: https://d311uvhi8lkjbj.cloudfront.net/media/Datasheet/pdf/.fAZ_VuVX/.t949edc23fade0802fd02/Datasheet-334/RPX-1_0.pdf

It is probably not OK to use the configuration in your first arrangement. Note the line in the absolute maximums ratings table:
$$V_{out} \text{ max} = V_{in} + \text{0.3VDC}$$

If \$V_{in}\$ is 0V, then \$V_{out}\$ should be less than 0.3V. "Exceeding these ratings may damage the device." (Actually, it's not necessarily true that Vin will be 0V when disconnected, but it's a conservative assumption).

So you should probably use your second arrangement. Another option is to find a double pole, double throw switch and switch both the inputs and outputs at the same time.